# InvalidArgumentException when calling D3D's CreateRasterizerState1

Tags: c++, direct3d, directx-11

I am working in DirectX 11 via C++ and I am getting an error when creating a raserizer state. First, here is the code:

```
// set up rasterizer
D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC1 rasterizerStateDescription;
::ZeroMemory(&rasterizerStateDescription, sizeof(D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC1));
rasterizerStateDescription.FillMode = D3D11_FILL_WIREFRAME;
ID3D11RasterizerState1* rasterizerState;
DX::ThrowIfFailed(m_d3dDevice->CreateRasterizerState1(&rasterizerStateDescription, &rasterizerState));
m_d3dContext->RSSetState(rasterizerState);
```

Setting FillMode there doesn't really matter - that's just included to illustrate my usage. I've tried setting all of the members, and none of them. In the debugger I can see that all of the other members have their default values.

The error is thrown at CreateRaserizerState1, and is:

```
First-chance exception at 0x75EC4B32 in my.exe: 
Microsoft C++ exception: 
Platform::InvalidArgumentException ^ at memory location 0x028DE2CC. 
HRESULT:0x80070057
```

As far as I can tell, raserizerStateDescription and rasterizerState are both valid, so I'm not clear as to why I am getting an invalid argumet exception here.

Commenting out the CreateRasterizerState1 and RSSetState calls allow the application to run normally.

Any suggestions as to how this can be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. The problem was that I wasn't specifying DepthClipEnable == true. Because I'm targeting feature level 9.1, [DepthClipEnable must be true](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476150%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#ID3D11Device_CreateRasterizerState), and because I was zeroing the memory I was effectively setting it to false.